# Want to install drivers for FLDIGI using rasbian

Tags: driver

I have an issue trying to run FLDIGI with My Yaesu FT-991a.  Everything I read says i need drivers to make it work but best i can find is this driver  [https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers
][1]

Its for Linux so I assume it will be compatible for Rasbian

I have read a lot about installing drivers in rasbian but all of it is specific to whatever driver the discussion is about.  Having a hard time trying for figure out the command line I would need to do this. Seems that as this is a newer radio there is very little direct instruction and it all involves either windows or mac. Would like to figure it out so i can pass it a long to others in the Ham community. Do a lot of emergency communications and this would be a perfect setup if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Always good to see a fellow ham radio operator here on StackExchange!
Assuming you're logged-in at the base of your home directory (we'll use username 'pi' for the sake of this answer)

**First we'll download and extract the file:**

1. On your Raspberry Pi, download this [Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip](https://www.silabs.com/documents/login/software/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip) (we'll assume it goes into your ~/Downloads folder).
2. From a terminal window, type:

   > mkdir drivers

(you can call this anything, I named it drivers, adjust accordingly downstream)

3. Type:

   > mv ~/Downloads/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip ./drivers/
4. > cd ./drivers
5. At the command line type:

   > unzip 3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip
6. For some reason Silicon Labs put a compressed file within a compressed file.  So we need to extract/decompress one more time:

   > tar -xvzf Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.tar.gz
7. Make your cp210x driver by typing:

   > make
8. Copy the driver to the correct location:

   > cp cp210x.ko to /lib/modules/4.9.80-v7+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/
   >   **OR**
   >   cp cp210x.ko to /lib/modules/4.9.80+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/
9. Insert the module into the kernel

   > insmod /lib/modules/4.9.80-v7+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
   >   **OR**
   >   insmod /lib/modules/4.9.80+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
10. Install the driver:

    > insmod cp210x.ko
11. Reboot

    > sudo reboot

73 and Good Luck!
K6JEB

Comment: after trying to extract .tar getting this: pi@raspberrypi:/drivers $ tar -xvzf Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.tar.gz
tar (child): Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now any ideas why i getting this? Regards, Kes.